# AWS Cognito auth with cUrl

Tags: curl, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I try to connect my API Gateway with Cognito authorization.
After adding the existing user pool to the API I tried to get an accesstoken from cognito. For this I tried:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -H "Authorization: Basic <your_base_64>" \
  --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<cognito_client_id>&scope=openid" \
  "https://<your_domain>.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
```

I tried to use a userpool Authorization string (userid:usepass) here I get invalid client as reponse. After this I tried the cognito client_id:client_secret as Authorization sting and now I get invalid grant.
All Authorization strings were base64 encoded.
Someone please can give me a hint wht I do wrong or what I miss?